# How to find motion vectors from a video using python

Tags: python, image-processing, vector, motion, opticalflow

After reading some research papers related to video processing and deep learning I found that motion vectors are a good choice to extract temporal information faster than optical flow-based methods.

can anyone help me in this direction?

And how to do it in python?

Comment: With which parts should anyone help you? What have you tried so far, where **exactly** are you stuck?

Comment: @Nico Haase I am actually new in this area of video processing,  so ain't got much idea how to start